# Dictionary of <Type, List<Type>>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, typesafe

I want to implement a wrapper class for a Dictionary that maps a Type to a generic List of that Type. For example:

```
**Key**               **Value**
typeof(InterfaceA), List<InterfaceA>
typeof(InterfaceB), List<InterfaceB>
typeof(MyClass), List<MyClass>
...
```

I then want to interact with the wrapper class by using types.

```
public void NewEntry<T>()
{
    MyDict.Add(typeof(T), new List<T>());
}

public List<T> GetEntry<T>()
{
    return MyDict[typeof(T)];
}

public void RemoveEntry<T>()
{
    MyDict.Remove(typeof(T));
}
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?

EDIT: to clarify, the point of this is so that with

```
GetEntry<MyInterface>()
```

the items in the list are guaranteed to follow the contract of MyInterface. Each entry would have a different Type key, and each List of items would follow the contract of that Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following static class

```
public static class GenericLists
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> MyDict = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    public static void NewEntry<T>()
    {
        MyDict.Add(typeof(T), new List<T>());
    }

    public static List<T> GetEntry<T>()
    {
        return (List<T>)MyDict[typeof(T)];
    }

    public static void RemoveEntry<T>()
    {
        MyDict.Remove(typeof(T));
    }

}
```

Or you could use

```
public class GenericLists<T>
{
    private Dictionary<Type, List<T>> MyDict = new Dictionary<Type, List<T>>();

    public void NewEntry()
    {
        MyDict.Add(typeof(T), new List<T>());
    }

    public List<T> GetEntry()
    {
        return MyDict[typeof(T)];
    }

    public void RemoveEntry()
    {
        MyDict.Remove(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

if you really want to initialize it, but I think the static will work better.

Comment: Why is the `value` an *object* when you add it as `new List<T>()`

Comment: If the data is static, you can do it without any casts.  See my answer.

Comment: Now what is different. You just repeated the question.

Comment: @SLaks that would be another option if I made the static class generic.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to store everything statically, you can use the type system:

```
static class MyDict {
    private static class Data<T> {
        public static readonly List<T> items = new List<T>();
    }
    public static List<T> Get<T>() { return Data<T>.items; }
    public static void Add<T>(T item) { Data<T>.items.Add(item); }
}
```

Note that this makes it impossible to remove a key (you can't unload a type), although you can `Clear()` it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as an instance-based class also (see below), but my preference, if it works for you, is to use a static variable in a static class as SLaks demonstrated in the "use the type system" post.

```
public class GenericTypeListDictionary
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _dictionaryOfLists = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public List<T> NewEntry<T>()
    {
        var newList = new List<T>();
        _dictionaryOfLists.Add(typeof(T), newList);
        return newList;
    }

    public List<T> GetEntry<T>()
    {
        object value;

        if (_dictionaryOfLists.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out value))
        {
            return (List<T>)value;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void RemoveEntry<T>()
    {
        _dictionaryOfLists.Remove(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't lock on a `Type` object.  Also, locking in only one method is pointless, and locking on the value type is even more pointless.

Comment: I removed the lock command.  It crept in because of a completely unrelated discussion I was having.  However, I don't understand the assertion that locking in only one method is pointless when you are dealing with a multi-threaded application.

Comment: I mean locking in only one method when other methods modify the same structure.  That's like building a gate across only half of a walkway.

Comment: Implying that if I lock the .Add, I should also lock the .Remove.  Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: And the .Get.  And, you need to always lock on the same object, since you're trying to protect access to the dictionary, not the list.  (and in practice, a `ConcurrentDictionary` would be better)